# How to improve the performance when working with wikipedia data and huge no. of webpages?

Tags: java, hadoop, ontology, text-mining, wikimedia-dumps

I am supposed to extract representative terms from an organisation's website using wikipedia's article-link data dump.
To achieve this I've -

1. Crawled & downloaded organisation's webpages. (~110,000)
2. Created a dictionary of wikipedia ID and terms/title. (~40million records)

Now, I'm supposed to process each of the webpages using the dictionary to recognise terms and track their term IDs & frequencies.

For the dictionary to fit in memory, I've splitted the dictionary into smaller files. Based on my experiment with a small data-set, the processing time for the above will be around 75 days.

And this is just for 1 organisation. I have to do the same for more than 40 of them.

Implementation -

- HashMap for storing dictionary in memory.
- looping through each map entry to search the term in a webpage, using Boyer-Moore search implementation.
- Repeating the above for each webpage, and storing results in a HashMap.

I've tried optimizing the code and tuning the JVM for better performance.

Can someone please advise on a more efficient way to implement the above, reducing the processing time to a few days.

Is Hadoop an option to consider?

Comment: You should definitely use Lucene for this task.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik. I will checkout Lucene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question:

```
Number of Documents = 110000

Dictionary => List of [TermID, Title Terms] = 40million entries

Size of documents = 11000 * 1KB per document on an average =  26.9GB
(1KB per document on an average)

Size of dictionary = 40million * 256bytes = 9.5GB of raw data
(256bytes per entry on an average)
```

How did you arrive at the 75 days estimate?

There are number of performance targets:

- How are you storing the Documents?
- How are you storing/retrieving the Dictionary? ( assuming not all of it in memory unless you can afford to)
- How many machines are you running it on?
- Are you performing the dictionary lookups in parallel? ( of-course assuming dictionary is immutable once you have already processed whole of wikipedia )

Here is an outline of what I believe you are doing:

```
dictionary = read wikipedia dictionary
document = a sequence of documents
documents.map { doc =>
  var docTermFreq = Map[String, Int]()
  for(term <- doc.terms.map if(dictionary.contains(term)) ) {
     docTermFreq = docTermFreq + (term -> docTermFreq.getOrElse(term, 0) + 1)
  }
  // store docTermFreq map
}
```

What this is essentially doing is breaking up each document into tokens and then performing a lookup in wikipedia dictionary for its token's existence.

This is exactly what a [Lucene Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) does.

A [Lucene Tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html) will convert document into tokens. This happens before the terms are indexed into lucene. So all you have to do is implement a Analyzer which can lookup the Wikipedia Dictionary, for whether or not a token is in dictionary.

I would do it like this:

- Take every document and prepare a token stream ( using an Analyzer described above )
- Index the document terms.
- At this point you will have wikipedia terms only, in the Lucene Index.

When you do this, you will have ready-made statistics from the Lucene Index such as:

- [Document Frequency](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#docFreq%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term%29) of a Term
- [TermFrequencyVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermFreqVector.html) ( exactly what you need )
- and a ready to use inverted index! ( for a quick introduction to [Inverted Index and Retrieval](http://xapian.org/docs/intro_ir.html) )

There are lot of things you can do to improve the performance. For example:

- Parallelize the document stream processing.
- You can store the dictionary in key-value database such as [BerkeylyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) or Kyoto Cabinet, or even an in-memory key-value storage such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcache](http://memcached.org/).

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was using [monq library](http://monqjfa.berlios.de/) to do the same, but it seems quite complex. So, i'm planning to use Lucene. I've Googled for building a custom analyzer, but it'll be great if you can direct me to a good resource. Also, I want to point that wikipedia dictionary has multi-word terms(phrases). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that use only MR is to:

Assuming you already have N dictionaries of smaller size that fit to memory you can:
Launch N "map only" jobs that will be scanning all your data (each one with only one dictionary) and output smth like {pageId, termId, occurence, etc} to folder /your_tmp_folder/N/
As a result you will have N*M files where M is amount of mappers on each stage(should be the same).

Then second job will simply analyze your {pageId, termId, occurence, etc} objects and build stats per page id.

Map only jobs should be very fast in your case. If not - please paste your code.